# Let $_0, _1, _2, …$ be the sequence defined by the following recurrence relation:

Tags: recurrence-relations, proof-explanation

Let $_0, _1, _2, …$ be the sequence defined by the following recurrence
relation:

$_0 = 2$

$_1 = 2$

$_2 = 6$

$_ = 3_{−3}$ for $ ≥ 3$

Prove that  is even for any nonnegative integer .
a. The base cases are  = ,  = , and  = .

$_ = , _ = ,$ and $_ = $ are even.

Thus, the statement is true for  = ,  = , and  = .

b. Assume that $_$ is even for  ≤  ≤  and  ≥ .

That is, $_ = _$ for some integer .

c. Show that if the inductive hypothesis is true, then $_{+}$ is even.

d. $_{+} = _{−}$

$_{+} = ()$ (inductive hypothesis) **-> From where does this come from**

$_{+} = ()$

Let  be an integer such that  = .

Then, $_{+} = .$

Thus, $_{+}$ is even.

Therefore, by strong induction, the statement is true for any nonnegative
integer .

Can anyone please explain me how does $_ = _$ and also the proof part. From where does the inductive hypothesis come from in the proof.

Comment: It should be $a_j=2i$ for some integer $i$.  The $i$ is a multiplier not a subscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even number is divisible by 2, so it is of the form $2i$ (not $2_i$) for some natural (or integer) $i$.

Probably easier to understand will be if you temporary forget induction. Because $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$ are even, their multiplications by 3 are also even, and their multiplication by 3 are also even, and so on. But it is an informal induction, which can be formalized as in your proof.

Comment: Can you please explain from where does this come from and how $_{+} = ()$ (inductive hypothesis)

Comment: @tienlee $a_{k+1}=3a_{k-2}$ from the definition. But from the inductive hypothesis all $a_i$, where $0\leq1\leq k$, are even. So $a_{k-2}=2i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Is this also correct  a) Base cases $a_1$ $=4$ and $a_2 = 12$ are both divisible by $4$.

  b) Suppose there is an integer j such that aj is divisible by $4$ for $1 <= j <= k$ where $k >= 2.$

  c) Prove that $a_(k+1)$ is divisible by $4.$

  d) $a_(k+1)$ = $a_(k) + a_(k-1)$ for all integers $k+1 >= 3$

      By the inductive hypothesis we know that a(k) and a(k-1) are within the bounds, so they are divisible by 4.

      $a_(k+1) = 4j + 4l$

      $a_(k+1) = 4(j + l)$ (So, this shows $a_(k+1)$ is divisible by $4$).

Answer (score 0):

The general term is: $a_n=6\cdot 3^{\lfloor\frac{n-2}{3}\rfloor},n\ge 2,$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a floor function.

Comment: Is this also correct  a) Base cases $a_1$ $=4$ and $a_2 = 12$ are both divisible by $4$.

  b) Suppose there is an integer j such that aj is divisible by $4$ for $1 <= j <= k$ where $k >= 2.$

  c) Prove that $a_(k+1)$ is divisible by $4.$

  d) $a_(k+1)$ = $a_(k) + a_(k-1)$ for all integers $k+1 >= 3$

      By the inductive hypothesis we know that a(k) and a(k-1) are within the bounds, so they are divisible by 4.

      $a_(k+1) = 4j + 4l$

      $a_(k+1) = 4(j + l)$ (So, this shows $a_(k+1)$ is divisible by $4$).

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_i = 3a_{i−3} = 2a_{i−3}+a_{i−3}$, we have $a_i$ is even iff $a_{i−3}$ is even.

Since $a_0, a_1, a_2$ are all even, we conclude that $a_n$ is even for all $n$.

Comment: Is this also correct  a) Base cases $a_1$ $=4$ and $a_2 = 12$ are both divisible by $4$.

  b) Suppose there is an integer j such that aj is divisible by $4$ for $1 <= j <= k$ where $k >= 2.$

  c) Prove that $a_(k+1)$ is divisible by $4.$

  d) $a_(k+1)$ = $a_(k) + a_(k-1)$ for all integers $k+1 >= 3$

      By the inductive hypothesis we know that a(k) and a(k-1) are within the bounds, so they are divisible by 4.

      $a_(k+1) = 4j + 4l$

      $a_(k+1) = 4(j + l)$ (So, this shows $a_(k+1)$ is divisible by $4$).